# SQL sort equal values using case

Tags: sql, sql-server

A similar question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340648/sql-need-to-sort-the-value-using-group-by-or-any-other-way). But current scenario is little bit complex than previous. In the example if same `Itime` then we can can sort by case but if `Itime` and result is same then how can I sort.

My question is, here the result ID:  3,5,6,1,2,7,8,4. Why it is 2,7,8 for fail case .

Why it is not 8,2,7?

If I want the expected result like: 3,5,1,6,8,2,7,4 how can I proceed?

Please run the below commands and help me to sort. Thanks in advance.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#temp321','U') is not null
   drop table tempdb.dbo.#temp321

create table #temp321(id int, uname varchar(50), current_point int, 
                      previous_point int, ITime datetime, Result varchar(10))

INSERT into #temp321 values('1','a','50','40','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','pass')
INSERT into #temp321 values('2','b','15','10','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','fail')
INSERT into #temp321 values('3','c','71','70','2012-11-12 12:58:30.000','pass')
INSERT into #temp321 values('4','d','34','30','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','withdraw')
INSERT into #temp321 values('5','e','40','35','2012-11-12 12:58:41.360','withdraw')
INSERT into #temp321 values('6','f','65','60','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','pass')
INSERT into #temp321 values('7','g','20','15','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','fail')
INSERT into #temp321 values('8','h','10','7','2012-11-12 13:12:28.103','fail')


select 
    ID 
from 
    #temp321 
ORDER BY 
    ITime ASC,
    CASE Result 
       WHEN 'pass' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'fail' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'withdrow' THEN 3 
    END 

drop table #temp321
```

- Current output ID: 3,5,6,1,2,7,8,4
- Expected Output ID: 3,5,1,6,8,2,7,4

Comment: Because your table is a heap table, when two or more rows have the same sort key, in this case '2912-11-12 13:12:28.103', 2, then the rows will be returned in an order based upon your query plan. In this case it is a table scan and therefore the rows will be ordered based upon their location in the heap table (the order they were inserted). I am unable to work out how you have decided that 8,2,7,4 is the sort order that you wnat.

Comment: Are you wanting to sort by current_point too? you don't mention.

Comment: Steve, that might explain why the 2, 7, 8; but it does not explain why it's selecting 6 before 1.  Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: riad, I assume that row 4 and your query should refer to "withdraw" instead of "withdrow"?

Comment: Thanks every body. Basically i missed the heap table concept. I have needed to know that how the query engine process the order.Thanks Steven for his explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The current query will NOT deliver the same order every time.

For me your example delivers:

```
3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 8, 4 (Note 1 and 6 being swapped)
```

1 and 6 are "equal" compared to their sort values taking into account for sorting. And if no sorting is specified (or equal sortings) the order within that bunch is - per definition - undefined. (depends on the order threads created the data)

Same applies for `2, 7, 8`. You want the order `3, 5, 1, 6, 8, 2, 7, 4` - so you seem to "have" a logic how you expect it to be sorted? Then add that condition and you are done :)

(for your expected output adding current_point is what you want - but YOU have to know if you want to sort by that column)

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp321 
ORDER BY ITime ASC,
  CASE Result 
    WHEN 'pass'     THEN 1 
    WHEN 'fail'     THEN 2 
    WHEN 'withdraw' THEN 3 
  END, current_point ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. i need to know the order processes way & i get my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subquery with as key value pair:

```
   SELECT 'pass' value, 1 priority UNION ALL         
   SELECT 'fall' value, 2 priority UNION ALL
   SELECT 'withdraw' value, 3 priority UNION ALL
```

Then do a join to a subquery on value column and order by priority, that will give you cleaner solution. You can even create temporary table and index by value if there are a lot of lookup values, to ensure speed is appropriate.